# iPhone Camera: Is there a way to show camera directly from web, don´t show Photo Library Option

Tags: javascript, ios, html, web, camera

I´m trying to open the camera of my iphone from a webpage, I read the code should be something like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

But can I prevent it of showing the  "Photo Library" option? I want the camera to open directly when i press a button.

Thanks,